# How can I ensure that if petalinux has configured oled drivers for me

Tags: zynq, petalinux

my friends, I have a confusing question here,

I have a zedboard ,I want to construct a application on linux system to draw some letters on oled screen.

and I use vivado to add zynq-7000 core, and oled IP core through AXI, then got .xsa file. Then use petalinux2022.2 to get linux images and something I need to flash to SD

here is my question: when I use petalinux to construct the image, does it already include the oled driver? Or I need to write by myself? if I have to write by myself， how can i do it, thanks